How to design deformed text in sphere shape using Blender geometry nodes

I tried to achieve a similar effect using Blender's Sverchok nodes but couldn't get satisfactory results. The letters deform too much. How can I achieve this using geometry nodes instead? Thanks in advance to anyone who can provide an answer.

I could be wrong, but I would be surprised if there is a viable solution here with Geometry Nodes alone that would not go beyond the scope of this platform. Since you also don't show here what you have tried so far with Geometry Nodes and what problem exactly you are currently failing at, I would tend to close the question as "too extensive/localized". The difficulties lie in the fact that the letters themselves are distorted seamlessly, the distances are obviously filled in and then there must also be enough geometry to bring this into a spherical shape. Nevertheless, an interesting question.

Hello, @quellenform  Looking at the original tutorial.. we're looking for remapping by bilinear interpolation   across quad faces, like the Tissue add-on.. should be possible, I reckon, there's no interlocking packing going on, or anything..

link italic bold code
I tried the tutorial in the link, but as I mentioned, I couldn't maintain the deformation at a level where the letters are recognizable. Perhaps I couldn't master the settings properly, or it's not possible with Sverchok nodes. I'm not sure. I have added the image of what I created to the question.

@RobinBetts Hm, yes, that would be possible. And perhaps I was thinking too complicatedly again or took the picture shown a little too precisely ...

You reference seems to map instances to quads, using bilinear interpolation.
The strategy here is:

Prepare an all-quad sphere to receive letters

Store their own dimensions on letter instances, using the method illustrated here, but with updated nodes

Using those dimensions, map all instances to the unit square

Transfer face-corner positions for each quad face receiving geometry to corresponding instances, by face-index -> instance index

Realize instances, and map their point positions, using the 0-1 point XY's ('UV') as mix parameters, to positions in their corresponding quad faces (as shown below):




Normalize new letter point-positions to a sphere, and extrude.




...Excellent answer, proving that sometimes I can't see the obvious

Thanks, Q! .. :) very kind!  Looking back at OP's edit, I think they might have been almost there without all this? Maybe just needing to prepare letters more suitably for deformation.. and 't' s 'i' s etc don't take very kindly to this mapping ..Sneakily left out of the tutorial, perhaps ... >8D

Thank you very much @RobinBetts. Great solution. Thanks a lot for the project file too.
